# How to bind property to getter-only CLR Property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, dependency-properties

For some purpose I wanted to raise an event whenever the `LineCount` of a multiline textbox changes

I thought I could achieve this if I bind a dependency property to  `TextBox.LineCount`

Below is the code sample

**XAML**

```
<local:MyTextBox Margin="5,65,5,5" x:Name="txtBox" 
       AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="False" 
       MyProperty="{Binding LineCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

**Code-Behind**

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(LineCountProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(LineCountProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyProperty",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(TextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new PropertyChangedCallback(
             (dp, args) => { MessageBox.Show(args.NewValue.ToString()); })
        ));
}
```

The messagebox is shown only when the form is loaded and not after the line count changes.

However if I change the Binding for the `MyProperty` from TextBox's `LineCount` to `Text`
The PropertyChangedEvent is fired everytime the text changes.

I am sure I can fire some custom LineCount changed event from TextChanged eventhandler, but I want to do this via `DepedencyProperties` for I believe it'll be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `LineCount` is not a dependency property, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount.aspx). For this reason it does not support binding and will not provide change notification.

Considering that you are making a custom control, do you really need to use binding? Why not just handle the `TextChanged` event internally and detect when the line count changes manually.

Comment: Can't you bind to any property? I thought only the target has to be a DP.